# Python 3 Convert IPV4Address to string

Tags: python-3.x, types, ip-address, socks

I am attempting to convert an IPV4Address in python3 to a `string` or `int` as per the error message below. I'm not quite sure I'm doing wrong here. I also tried `int(x)` and `bytes(x)` neither work

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/krisarmstrong/PycharmProjects/pyportscanner/pyportscanner", line 113, in <module>
main()
  File "/Users/krisarmstrong/PycharmProjects/pyportscanner/pyportscanner", line 105, in main
get_ip_address()
   File "/Users/krisarmstrong/PycharmProjects/pyportscanner/pyportscanner", line 70, in get_ip_address
result = sock.connect_ex((x, port))
TypeError: str, bytes or bytearray expected, not IPv4Address
```

My code is as follows:

```
def get_ip_address():
ip_address_list = []
port = '2359'
network = ipaddress.ip_network('10.0.16.0/20')
for x in network.hosts():
    str(x)
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    result = sock.connect_ex((x, port))
    if result == 0:
        print("Port"), port(" Open")
    sock.close()
    ip_address_list.append(x)
return ip_address_list
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code snippet (relevant lines below), the `str(x)` line returns `x` as a string but does store this string in `x`. You need to do `x = str(x)` to store the string representation in `x` (or just use `str(x)` in place of `x` when calling `connect_ex`).

```
for x in network.hosts():
    str(x)
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    result = sock.connect_ex((x, port))
```

Comment: You could assign the value of str(x) to x, like `x = str(x)`.

Answer (score 0):

you forgot to assign the value of str(x) to x, the corrected version is:

```
for x in network.hosts():
    x = str(x)
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    result = sock.connect_ex((x, port))
```